# Orchard Admin route calls wrong MVC controller

Tags: model-view-controller, module, routes, admin, orchardcms

I am creating an Orchard module which provides the following route

```
public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Orchard.Mvc.Routes.RouteDescriptor> GetRoutes()
{
  Orchard.Mvc.Routes.RouteDescriptor[] lRoutes =
    new Orchard.Mvc.Routes.RouteDescriptor[] 
    {
      new Orchard.Mvc.Routes.RouteDescriptor()
      {
        Name = "Admin URL",
        Priority = 0, 
        Route = new System.Web.Routing.Route(
          "RetailSector/Mailing/Admin",
          new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary() { {"area", "MyModuleName"}, {"controller", "Admin"}, {"action", "Index"} }, 
          new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary(),
          new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary() { {"area", "MyModuleName"} },
          new System.Web.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler()
        )
      }
    };

  return lRoutes;
}
```

and when i type

```
http://localhost:30321/OrchardLocal/RetailSector/TuesdayMail/Admin
```

into the browser, Orchard routes into the Orchard Admin (Dashboard) instead of showing my admin view. I tried different priorities, does not work. Then i tried changing the controller name from Admin to lets say Administration and suddenly it works.

Is there a way to get the route working with the word "Admin"?

Update:

A breakpoint in `AdminController.Index()` method gets hit, thus my `AdminController` is used correctly by the routing system but after `return View()` the Orchard Dashboard is displayed?!? Adding a view parameter like `return View("Test")` which should result in displaying `Views\Admin\Test.cshtml` also does not work. I think i am facing a Orchard debug session.

Comment: Orchard automatically resolves any `AdminController` to the admin theme, including the navigation and everything. It resolves as if the `[Admin]` attribute is added to the controller.

Comment: @devqon Is there a way to change this?

Comment: I'm not sure how Orchard resolves those names. I suggest renaming the controller: be consistent that any `AdminController` is indeed an Orchard admin controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orchard automatically resolves any controller that is named `AdminController` to be themed with the Admin theme (the dashboard). It acts the same as if you apply the `[Admin]` attribute to a controller.

Looking at the code of Orchard.Framework.UI.Admin.AdminFilter.cs on lines 40-55:

```
private static bool IsAdmin(AuthorizationContext filterContext) {
    if (IsNameAdmin(filterContext) || IsNameAdminProxy(filterContext)) {
        return true;
    }

    var adminAttributes = GetAdminAttributes(filterContext.ActionDescriptor);
    if (adminAttributes != null && adminAttributes.Any()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private static bool IsNameAdmin(AuthorizationContext filterContext) {
    return string.Equals(filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName, "Admin",
                            StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

It checks if the current context is admin by checking if the controller's name is Admin.

You'll probably want to stay consistent of how Orchard handles this filtering. So I suggest renaming your controller if you don't want to apply the admin theme.

Comment: Yep i came to that conclusion to, my controller is now named AdministrationController, a bit ugly but i works.